# Join of simplicial sets induces a functor.

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory, functors

Given a simplicial set $X$, denote by $(\mathrm{Set}_{\Delta})/_X$ the over category, whose objects are morphisms of simplicial sets with source $X$. I want to show that the joint $X \star Y$ of simplicial sets induces a functor 
\begin{align*}
X \star - \colon \mathrm{Set}_{\Delta} & \to (\mathrm{Set}_{\Delta})/_X\\
Y & \mapsto X \hookrightarrow X \star Y
\end{align*}

There has to be something really stupid that I'm missing, because I can't make sense of what that functor is supposed to do on morphisms. Given a morphism $p \colon Y_1 \to Y_2$ of simplicial sets, I'm suppose to define a map $$f \colon X \star Y_1 \to X \star Y_2$$
such that the composite of the inclusion $X \hookrightarrow X \star Y$ and $f$ is the same as the inclusion $X \hookrightarrow X \star Y_2$.

My only guess is that $p \colon Y_1 \to Y_2$ induces a morphism 
$$\tilde{p} \colon X \star Y_1 \to X \star Y_2$$
via
\begin{align*}
\tilde{p}_n \colon (X \star Y_1)_n & \to (X \star Y_2)_n\\
\coprod_{[i]\oplus [j] = [n]} X_i \times (Y_1)_j & \mapsto \coprod_{[i]\oplus [j] = [n]} X_i \times p_j(Y_1)_j
\end{align*}

But I don't know why this map satisfy the commutativity condition with respect to the inclusions $X \hookrightarrow \to X \star Y_k, k \in \{1,2\}$.

Comment: Well it is satisfied dimensionwise, so it is satisfied globally